# Save a string, double and table Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a loop which runs 100 times. In each iteration there is a `string`, `double` and a `table` assigned, and in the next iteration new values are assigned for them. What I want to do is to accumulate these values and after the loop finishes save the total result as `result.mat` using the matlab `save` function. I've tried putting them in cell-array but its not working so far, so if anyone could please advise how this can be done.

This is what I did:

```
results_cell=(100,3);
.
.
.
results_cell(i,1)=stringA;
results_cell(i,2)=TableA;
results_cell(i,3)=DoubleA;
```

But it gives this error `Coversion to Cell from Table is not possible`. So I've tried converting `TableA` to array of Doubles using `table2array` but I still get this `Coversion to Cell from Double is not possible`

Comment: Why isn't it working? Can you show us a simple piece of code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Would you mind using a structure to store all those data types? That would be much simpler I think.

Comment: @Benoit_11 can you show me how?

Comment: Yes I'll write an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using a structure would be a good way to store your data, since they are of different types and you can assign it meaningful field names for easy reference.

For example, let's call the structure `Results`. You can initialize it like so.

```
Results = struct('StringData',[],'TableData',[],'DoubleData',[])
```

Since you know its dimensions, you can even do this:

```
N = 100;
Results(N).StringData = [];
Results(N).TableData = [];
Results(N).DoubleData = [];
```

This automatically create a 1xN structure with 3 fields.

Then in your loop you can assign each field with its associated data like so:

```
for k = 1:N

    Results(k).StringData = String(k);
    Results(k).TableData = Table(k);
    Results(k).DoubleData = Double(k);

end
```

where `String(k)`, `Table(k)` and `Double(k)` are just generic names for your actual data.

When you're done with the loop you can access any type of data using a single index and the right field name.

In order to save a .mat file, use something like this:

```
save SomeFileName.mat Results
```

Which you can load into the workspace as you would with any .mat file:

Eg:

```
S = load('SomeFileName.mat')

R = S.Results
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: @Benoit_11 why the string is saved with a single quote?

Comment: Mhh I don't see what you mean sorry. Where exactly?

Comment: the stringA I'm saving is a cell, so it has singlequotes, I don't want to save the singlequotes in the results_struct, I tried to use char(stringA) but still it is saved with single quotes, do you have any advice?

Comment: I don't understand sorry haha. It's a string in a cell? If you want to save the string you do need to keep the single quotes. Can you show a sample input?